# Compare two Excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file which contains two sheets. Both contains some data. I have to find common records of the two sheets(i.e., records which are present in both sheets). I can do it manually, but is there any tools/functions which exist to do this?

Comment: Minimally, you could convert to a csv and then run grep or something similar. You are looking for records that are identical in all ways? what do you want to do with them

Comment: I'd convert to CSV and then write a simple Java program or whatnot to extract the relevant sections for comparison with your favorite diff tool.  Or have the program compare them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use VLOOKUP depending on how complex your key structure is.

(Do a search on the Microsoft Office Support website for VLOOKUP.)

Comment: Link is unfortunately dead.

Comment: Grumble grumble.  I guess when you're Microsoft, you don't have to worry about creating 301 redirects when you restructure a site.

Answer (score 2):

You can covert it .csv and there are lots of options

If you have access to Unix you can run `diff <file1> <file2>` or `sdiff <file1> <file2>`

If you have access to `TortoiseSVN` or `TortoiseGit` or `Eclipse`, you can diff those two files and the differences will be done on screen. For `Tortoise` select the two files and click `Diff`. For `eclipse` drag those two files into the gui, select and choose `diff`

If the files are not very big try - http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html
You can put your text into the two boxes and run a diff using a proven diff algorithm [Myer's diff]

If you are Windows you can use WinDiff or WinMerge - http://winmerge.org/ . I personally use WinMerge as it can diff directories.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ``diff``/``sdiff`` are great tools for when you have two files that are largely the same, with a few lines different. They are not so useful for files that are largely different with a few lines the same.

Answer (score 2):

If the cells would be in the exact same location in each sheet, you can use a third sheet, then fill down and right with this formula:

```
    =IF('Sheet1'!A1<>'Sheet2'!A1,"Different", "-")
```

to compare the changes, where "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are your sheet names.

Answer (score 1):

There are several formulas you can use in Excel depending on what you want to do. The formulas all require a single-column key on both tables that they use to match rows. If you don't have a single-column key, then you need to create one. For example, if your data is in B2 to H500 and the key is the first three columns, create your single-column key in cell A2 with `=B2&"-"&C2"-"&D2` and copy it down to the other rows. Do this in both tables and now you have a key column to use.

The main two formulas I would use in Excel are `=COUNTIF(range, criteria)` and `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, FALSE)`. `COUNTIF` counts how many times `criteria` in table1 is found in `range` table2. If the result is greater than zero, then the row is in both tables. `VLOOKUP` looks up the `lookup_value` table1 in `table_array` table2 and returns the value in column `col_index_num`. If `VLOOKUP` doesn't find a match, it returns `NA()`.

If you want to see info from table 2 in table 1, use `VLOOKUP`. If you just want to know if a row is in both tables, use `COUNTIF`.

If you don't want to add anything/or change the existing Excel tables, you can link to them in Access and run a basic query there. (Let me know if you want details on how to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

This tool [CompareIt](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm) does a good job at visually showing differences. It knows Excel natively.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free and it might be overkill for your needs, but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_multisheetexcel) has done a great job of comparing Excel sheets for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specialized tool. [Excel Diff](http://www.suntrap-systems.com/ExcelDiff/) seems to output result visually.
http://www.suntrap-systems.com/ExcelDiff/

Try to consider because there is a trial version.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, as nobody mentioned it here so far you could try also [Excel Compare by Formula Software](http://www.formulasoft.com/excel-compare.html) (it's paid software but comes with a free trial period).

[image]

---

Anyway the best solution, in my opinion, is maybe already stated on your question's comments: **export to CSV and then use any diff-tool you like to compare**, simple! ([a list of diff-tools here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools))