# I have a sheet that changes weekly, can I have a sheet that automatically shows what's new?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

first timer here.

I have a shared sheet that is being updated at least once a week with some changes to some columns/rows.

I would like to have another sheet that shows those rows and columns that have been changed like some sort of a ChangeLog automatically. Do you think it's possible with a formula and not with VBA? Would CELL help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Excel sheets](https://superuser.com/questions/407202/compare-two-excel-sheets)

Comment: If you would like to avoid any of the *diff* utilities I would probably just add time to each entry and then used filter to see what were added/changed since a point in time. I am wondering what you mean by *updated* - are the data in the sheet usually added, changed or even deleted?

Comment: What types of updates may be? changes only? add cells/rows/columns to the end? add cells/rows/columns to the middle?

Comment: I think a document that portrays what I mean would be better:
I have a following document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pMP1haN-swINMDILqHWNn9wWB1ddEU5Ws3yxNmlSUpc/edit?usp=sharing

In the first sheet, "Original sheet", I contain various data that I update from time to time. I do it fairly often, so I'd like to have it done automatically rather than manually like I do now. 
I'd like the Change log sheet to show a date and changes whenever I make some in the original sheet. I realise there may be no other way than VBA, so I welcome that solutions as well.